# Vectorizing nested for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, vectorization

I need to vectorize two nested for loops and dont know how to do it. One is for gray scale images and one for color images. I want to filter an image with the kuwahara filter. The code you see below is the last step I need to vectorize to get a fast function.

- the array img_kuwahara is in shape of mxn or mxnx3 (color image)
- the array index_min is in shape of mxn
- the array mean is in shape of 4xmxn (gray scale) or 3x4xmxn (color)

I need to get the right value out of the mean array into the img_kuwahara array.

**as sample data you can use the following arrays:**

**index_min** = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 2, 3],[3, 3, 2, 2, 2],[2, 3, 3, 0, 2],[0, 1, 1, 0, 3],[2, 1, 3, 0, 0]])

**mean** = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(4,5,5)) (gray scale images)

**mean** = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(3,4,5,5)) (color images)

row = 5, columns = 5

Thank you for your help

```
# Edit gray scale image
if len(image.shape) == 2:

    # Set result image
    img_kuwahara = np.zeros((row, columns), dtype=imgtyp)

    for k in range(0, row):
        for i in range(0, columns):
            img_kuwahara[k, i] = mean[index_min[k, i], k, i]



# Edit color image
if len(image.shape) == 3:

    # Set result image
    img_kuwahara = np.zeros((row, columns, 3), dtype=imgtyp)

    for k in range(0, row):
        for i in range(0, columns):
            img_kuwahara[k, i, 0] = mean[0][index_min[k, i], k, i]
            img_kuwahara[k, i, 1] = mean[1][index_min[k, i], k, i]
            img_kuwahara[k, i, 2] = mean[2][index_min[k, i], k, i]
```

Comment: Do you have some sample data you could post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first loop can be vectorized using [`np.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html):

```
j, i = np.meshgrid(range(columns), range(rows))
img_kuwahara = mean[index_min[i, j], i, j]
```

The second loop can be vectorized by using an additional [`np.moveaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html#numpy.moveaxis) (assuming that `mean` is actually a 4D array in that case, not a list of 3D arrays; otherwise just convert it):

```
j, i = np.meshgrid(range(columns), range(rows))
img_kuwahara = np.moveaxis(mean, 0, -1)[index_min[i, j], i, j]
```

Alternatively to `np.meshgrid` you can also use [`np.mgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) (which supports a more natural syntax):

```
i, j = np.mgrid[:rows, :columns]
```